# AngularJS open Link if condition

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I want to check an if condition inside an href in AngularJS:

```
<a class="button button-block" href="if(cond){#/app/abc}else{nothing}" ng-click="doSomething()">Suchen</a>
```

where cond is a condition that can be true or false and the link shall only be openend if this condition is fullfilled.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if yes how?

Comment: yes of course simply use ng-if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have something like below in which it will create a href with URL when `cond` is true, otherwise it will create a blank `href` which would not redirect to anywhere.

```
ng-href="{{cond? '#/app/abc': ''}}"
```

---

Otherwise do remove `href` from anchor tag, and handle redirect logic  from `ng-click`'s `doSomething` function itself with the help of `$location.path('#/app/abc')` **OR** `$state.go`(depends on which router engine you are using) for redirection.

Comment: I know did it as you said with an  $state.go('abc.def'); inside the controllers javascript file like described in here [Angular state.go](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: @FranzHuber23 if you are using `ui-router` then its absolutely fine to use `$state.go`

Comment: Yes, I use ui-router now, thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result with ng-if, you  can use below option

```
<div ng-if="cond" ng-show="cond">
  <a class="button button-block" href="#/app/abc" ng-click="doSomething()" ng-model="cond">Suchen</a>
</div>
<a class="button button-block" href="nothing" ng-click="doSomething()" ng-hide="cond" ng-model="cond">abc</a>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cond='sai';// comment to see abc link with href= nothing and uncomment to show href with mentioned path
});
```

To show difference, i have used different names- Suchen and abc

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrRoay